# Django migrate command doesn't create any table on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, wagtail, heroku-postgres

It shows that tables are successfully created when I do `heroku run -a "app-name" python manage.py migrate`

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ app_name... up, run.0000 (Free)
System check identified some issues:

...

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, home, sessions, taggit, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  ...
```

But when I create a superuser, it tells me that there is no table
Any suggestions? I’m sticking in it for 3 days now so I will be grateful for any help.

P.S. I use heroku postgresql hobby-dev.

P.P.S.

```
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

Base settings.py https://pastebin.com/DLh3KrK7
My production configuration (`settings.py`)

```py
from .base import *
import dj_database_url
import environ


DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass


environ.Env.read_env()
env = environ.Env()


DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db()
}
```

Comment: I did locate this neat package https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration

Comment: Even if I use this package, django always use sqlite

Comment: check for a local_settings.py file that may have database values in it. They will override your settings.py.

Comment: it may have to do with your environ package as well (looks like default is sqllite) https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

Re-check your database configuration. The error trace shows that it's using sqlite as the database backend, instead of Postgres as expected:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
```

This is then failing because the sqlite database is stored on the filesystem, and filesystems on Heroku are not persistent across commands - so the database you created in the `migrate` step no longer exists when you run `createsuperuser`.

Answer (score 0):

please run these command

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

please make sure that you in your installed app

```
'django.contrib.auth'
```

and tell me if you still got the same error and then please add your settings.py